# RestKit - Access QueryParameters in completionBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

26 to post a Object with the getObject method and map the response. 
I need to access the query parameters I used in the request when the download in complete.

Is there a way to access queryparameters or the request address from the completion block of a restKit completion block

Comment: Just in the completion block, not in the mapping? Just capture the value...

Comment: @wain. I am aware of that solution. You mean in a property or local variable, right? I wanted to eliminate the risk that the variable the request is based on is changed during the request. I wanted to make sure that I always assign the request parameter to the right mapping result. Is that possible?

Comment: i really have no idea what you're asking, why aren't you including it in the mapping result ?

Comment: oh. You are right. I will do that. I thought there may be an easy way around it. But you are completely right that will solve the problem. Thanks.